# How can I use this local .txt file in my js code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, parsing, filesystems

**I have succeeded in using MechanicalSoup (Python library) to scrape the data from my school's website(s) and have created two .txt files (upcomingFixturesData.txt and resultsFixturesData.txt) which I would like to use to fill the content of one of my tables (I'm using Gatsby as a single-page site). The .txt documents both look like this:**

22/03/2022 
4:15pm 
Hockey 
Hockey v SchoolName: U16 (a, leave at 3.00pm)

22/03/2022 
10:00am 
Fives 
Fives National Championships: U18 (SchoolName, leave at 9.00am)

22/03/2022 
4:00pm 
Netball 
Netball: Leavers v Common Room (h)

**Currently, my js code is using dummy data for the sports tables:**

```
export default function SportsSection() {
  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <RowWrapper>
        <Description>Fixtures</Description>
        <Row
          number="1"
          title="Football"
          subtitle="Boys' U14 A and B team v SchoolName (away, leave at 12:20pm)"
          time="14:30"
        />
        <Row
          number="2"
          title="Hockey"
          subtitle="Hockey v SchoolName: U16 and 2st XI (away, depart 2.00pm)"
          time="15:45"
        />
        <Row
          number="3"
          title="Netball"
          subtitle="Netball: A and B team v SchoolName (home)"
          time="16:20"
        />
        <Row
          number="4"
          title="Rowing"
          subtitle="J15 vs SchoolName (Location)"
          time="15:30"
        />
      </RowWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

**I made a similar table to show each pupil's timetable, which was much easier as it was already a .json file, and I was able to use a 'map':**

```
export default function TimetableSection() {
  const data = require("../../data/scraped/timetableWeekData.json")

  var days = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"]
  var d = new Date()
  var dayName = days[d.getDay()]
  var tmrName = days[d.getDay() + 1]

  var hrs = new Date().getHours()

  const todayData = data.events.filter(
    // event => event["start-date-display"] == "Today"
    event => event.description.includes(hrs <= 20 ? dayName : tmrName)
  )

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <RowWrapper>
        <Description>Timetable {hrs <= 20 ? "Today" : "Tomorrow"}</Description>
        {todayData.map((item, index) => (
          <Row
            number={index + 1}
            title={item.subject}
            color={item.colour}
            subtitle={item.chairperson + ", " + item.location}
            time={item.starttime}
          />
        ))}
      </RowWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
}
```

**Is there any way that I could map the .txt files in order to populate each of my table rows, or failing that, how else could I go about using this data (which is inside the project file system) in my javascript code?**

**Thanks so much for your help in advance!**

Comment: So you created the .txt files? why didn't you store the scrapped data as json then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply like this, but with this function, your txt require correct structure to mapping

```
const fs = require("fs");
const _ = require("lodash");

const fileTxt = fs.readFileSync("./test.txt", { encoding: "utf-8" });

const eachData = fileTxt.split(/^\r\n/gm); // split for each object

const resultArr = [];
let number = 0;
eachData.forEach((data) => {
  const arrOneData = data.split(/\r\n/gm); // split for each object property
  resultArr.push({
    number,
    date: arrOneData[0],
    time: arrOneData[1],
    title: arrOneData[2],
    subtitle: arrOneData[3],
  });
  number += 1;
});

console.log("resultArr", resultArr);

// resultArr [
//   {
//     number: 0,
//     date: '22/03/2022',
//     time: '4:15pm',
//     title: 'Hockey',
//     subtitle: 'Hockey v SchoolName: U16 (a, leave at 3.00pm)'
//   },
//   {
//     number: 1,
//     date: '22/03/2022',
//     time: '10:00am',
//     title: 'Fives',
//     subtitle: 'Fives National Championships: U18 (SchoolName, leave at 9.00am)'
//   },
//   {
//     number: 2,
//     date: '22/03/2022',
//     time: '4:00pm',
//     title: 'Netball',
//     subtitle: 'Netball: Leavers v Common Room (h)'
//   }
// ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Also, how could I run this browser-side as opposed to server-side? Otherwise, how could I run a .js script using another .js file? Thanks!

Comment: to run a js script function using another js

so the simplest should be

script.js
```module.export = function() {}```

using.js
```const scriptFunction = require(path_to_script);
     scriptFunction()
```